# Opening links in an embedded iFrame in new tab or having them resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I made my company a Squarespace site (using the easy way not the developer version) and I embedded the following code to bring up our job board. However the links for the jobs themselves open up inside the iframe and aren't sized correctly. I either need them to resize automatically or open in a new tab. I've tried suggestions from other answered questions using target = blank etc but with no luck. I'm new to this so either I'm just not doing it right or maybe that's not the right way to do that? Note: I don't have control over how the links open from the side of our job applicant system.

`<iframe frameborder="0" style="border-width:0;" id="iframe" width="100%" height="800" -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; overflow: auto></iframe>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 (function($){
     $('#iframe').attr('src', 'https://recruit.zoho.com/recruit/Portal.na?iframe=false&digest=FPpXqXyf2I6K.@Sy2hAtJ5sVcffXdNGHPB6QUPDd4l8-');
 })(jQuery);
 </script>`

Comment: if you cannot edit the CSS of the iframe content (and it is not responsive), then you can't do much: you will have to adapt your iframe and your site design to the content.

Answer (score 0):

So after searching all over for an answer Zoho was able to provide me a pretty quick solution for getting the jobs to open in a new tab. That tab isn't a responsive as I'd like but its more manageable. Posting the solution here in case anyone else comes across this problem.

Change the iframe=false to true inside the link provided. 
https://recruit.zoho.com/recruit/Portal.na?iframe=**false**&digest=FPpXqXyf2I6K.@Sy2hAtJ.......

to
https://recruit.zoho.com/recruit/Portal.na?iframe=**true**&digest=FPpXqXyf2I6K.@Sy2hAtJ........